# Finding Rows with same value and contracting cells

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I'm trying to find all rows in a single column with the same value. The program should delete all rows that occur multiple times, apart from one of the columns, which should contract all statements from the deleted rows. This is what I have so far, but I'm getting a loop error:

```
Sub tester()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim one As Integer
        one = 2
    Dim log As Integer
        log = 2
    Dim compare As Integer
        compare = one + 1
    Dim ws As String
        ws = "Sheet1"
    Dim ender As String
        ender = "Sheet4"
    Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0
    Dim lastrow As Integer
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For log = 2 To lastrow - 1
        one = log + counter
        compare = one + 1
        If Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 1).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(compare,1).Value And Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 7).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(compare, 7).Value Then
            Do While Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 1).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(compare, 1).Value And Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 7).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(compare, 7).Value
                If compare = one + 1 Then
                    Worksheets(ender).Cells(log, 1).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 1).Value
                    Worksheets(ender).Cells(log, 4).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 4).Value
                   Worksheets(ender).Cells(log, 2).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 2).Value
                   Worksheets(ender).Cells(log, 7).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 7).Value
                End If
                Worksheets(ender).Cells(log, 4).Value = Worksheets(ender).Cells(log, 4).Value & "; " & Worksheets(ws).Cells(compare, 4).Value
                compare = compare + 1
                counter = counter + 1
            Loop
        ElseIf Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 1).Value <> Worksheets(ws).Cells(compare, 1).Value Then
            Worksheets(ender).Cells(one - counter, 1).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 1).Value
            Worksheets(ender).Cells(one - counter, 2).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 2).Value
            Worksheets(ender).Cells(one - counter, 3).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 3).Value
            Worksheets(ender).Cells(one - counter, 4).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 4).Value
            Worksheets(ender).Cells(one - counter, 5).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 5).Value
            Worksheets(ender).Cells(one - counter, 7).Value = Worksheets(ws).Cells(one, 7).Value
        End If
    Next log
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
End Sub
```

Original Data
[image: This is a screenshot of my original Data]

Desired output
[image: This is a screenshot of my desired output]

Comment: post some screenshot to let us see a "before" and "after" scenario

Comment: I recommend to post the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks so much for helping out!! I've just posted a screenshot of my desired input and output. Hope it helps out. I'm getting an Error Code 6 Error, which according to a help website is a loop error.

Comment: The compiler says the error is on the lines "compare = compare + 1" but then finds a new error once I delete it